# DropDownList in my edit view mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have List view and in every rows it has the "Actualizar" link action and that one takes me to the edit view in which i have some dropdownLists available for updating my existing data but my big problem is that i want the dropdownlist to first load the data is save. how can i set the dropdownlist to load the data of the model a return and let me choose other options

controller:

```
   public ActionResult ActualizarDispositivo(int id )
    {
        dropDown();

      var equipo= _db.equipo.Include(m=>m.marca).Include(mo=>mo.modelo.Single(b => b.idEquipo==id);

        ViewBag.idMarca = _db.marca.ToList().Select(Mar => new SelectListItem
       {
           Value = Mar.idMarca.ToString(),
           Text = Mar.Descripcion.ToString(),
           Selected = true
       });


        return View("ActualizarDispositivo",equipo);
    }
```

in the edit view i have this

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.idMarca,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.idMarca)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using **should** work, if you simply remove the `Selected = true`. Currently you are setting all of the `DropDownList`'s values to selected.

I'm not sure which performs better, but I do find it more readable to create a select list using:

```
ViewBag.idMarca = new SelectList(_db.marca.ToList(), "idMarca", "Descripcion");
```

And then, there may be no need to cast. (Unsure, I avoid the use of `ViewBag`)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.idMarca, ViewBag.idMarca)
```

Comment: it should work but it doesn't, i don't really know i'm doing wrong,i have remove the select=true and i tried doing what you wrote up there with no success. i got an error @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.idMarca, ViewBag.idMarca)